had been working for us before... /part 2
a. He had been working for us before he started working for you.
I can see three possibilities:

He started working for you right after he stopped working for us.

There was a time lapse between the time he stopped working for us and he started working for you.

He kept on working for us after he started working for you.


Which of the cases 1-3 can correspond to (a)?
I don't think (a) could be used in case (2).
Many thanks

Since there is no further context all three options are possible.

Someone who overheard that remark, who didn't know the details of the story, might infer  from the continuous he had been working for us that he left the speaker's employ in order to start working for the person being spoken to. The inference is justified since the speaker is likely to have said "he had worked for us" if "he" hadn't left to go work for the other person but had left the speaker's employ well before be began working for the person being spoken to, and may well have had another job in between.  But it is only an inference drawn from the speaker's using the continuous.

The "natural" phrasing is obviously He worked for us before he started working for you, so the Continuous Perfect version is automatically "marked". So if it came from a competent speaker, the most likely nuance is (resentful) emphasis. There might be some other contextually specific nuance involved - the point is no-one would be likely to repeat the continuous verb forms unless they intended some nuance or other.

Unlike the present perfect continuous, which indicates an action that began in the past and has continued up to the present, the past perfect continuous indicates something that began in the past, continued in the past, and also ended at a defined point in the past.               Only 1 is correct
